# Pattern for generating names at command line when using mix to create an app skeleton

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

I am trying to learn Elixir and am using mix to generate a basic RestFul API skeleton:

```
% mix new MyApi --module MyApi
```

I get an error:

> ** (Mix) Application name must start with a lowercase ASCII letter, followed by lowercase ASCII letters, numbers, or underscores, got:
> "MyApi". The application name is inferred from the path, if you'd like
> to explicitly name the application then use the "--app APP" option

then I try this:

```
% mix new my-in-memory-api  --module MyApi
```

and I get this error:

> ** (Mix) Application name must start with a lowercase ASCII letter, followed by lowercase ASCII letters, numbers, or underscores, got:
> "my-in-memory-api". The application name is inferred from the path, if
> you'd like to explicitly name the application then use the "--app APP"
> option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mix new` uses the path as the app name by default. In your case, the path has dashes which are not allowed in an app name. To fix, you need to pass a valid app name like this:

```
$ mix new my-in-memory-api --app my_in_memory_api --module MyApi
```